# Is Fréchet derivative independent of the choice of norm?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces

I am taking a course on analysis on $\Bbb R^n$ spaces. I saw someone wrote something like "we can find the total derivative of this function in another equivalent norm". I am not sure if this method is correct. I will formulate my question here.

Let $(V,\lVert\cdot\rVert_V),(W,\lVert\cdot\rVert_W)$ be Banach spaces. Let $U\subseteq V$ be an open set and $f:U\to W$ be a function. Suppose $f$ is Fréchet differentiable at $x\in U$ with derivative being $L$.

Let ${\lVert\cdot\rVert_V}'$ and ${\lVert\cdot\rVert_W}'$ be two new norms on $V$ and $W$ respectively, with both of them being equivalent to the original norms respectively, and that $(V,{\lVert\cdot\rVert_V}'),(W,{\lVert\cdot\rVert_W}')$ are Banach spaces.

Does it follow that the function $f$ is still Fréchet differentiable at $x$ in these new norms, and the derivative is still $L$? If not, what if $V,W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces over $\Bbb R$?

Comment: A function is Frechet differentiable at a point with respect to _some_ norm if and only if it is differentiable with respect to _any_ equivalent norm (see proof below); the derivatives coincide at the point. In particular, since the standar norm is differentiable everywhere but zero, the $\ell^1$-norm is differentiable everywhere except zero (in fact, no norm is differentiable at zero), including points of the standard basis (which are peaks, in our geometric intuition). This shows, in particular, that the intuition of $\Bbb R$ of "not having peaks" is no longer true in several dimensions.

Comment: @WillM. why don't you just post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a second though, this is rather easy to show. Write $$c\lVert\cdot\rVert_V\le{\lVert\cdot\rVert_V}'\le C\lVert\cdot\rVert_V$$ and $$d\lVert\cdot\rVert_W\le{\lVert\cdot\rVert_W}'\le D\lVert\cdot\rVert_W$$ by norm equivalence. Then we have $$\frac{{\lVert\cdot\rVert_W}'}{{\lVert\cdot\rVert_V}'}\le\frac{C\lVert\cdot\rVert_W}{d\lVert\cdot\rVert_V}$$ as long as the denominator is nonzero. Apply squeeze theorem to see that $$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{{\lVert f(x+h)-f(x)-Lh\rVert_W}'}{{\lVert h\rVert_V}'}=0$$ when the expression $\frac{{\lVert f(x+h)-f(x)-Lh\rVert_W}'}{{\lVert h\rVert_V}'}$ is considered as a function $g:V\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb R$ with $h$ being its variable (i.e. $g(h):=\frac{{\lVert f(x+h)-f(x)-Lh\rVert_W}'}{{\lVert h\rVert_V}'}$), and the limit is taken in the metric induced by $\lVert\cdot\rVert_V$. Since the norms $\lVert\cdot\rVert_V$ and ${\lVert\cdot\rVert_V}'$ are equivalent, the same limit also holds in the metric induced by ${\lVert\cdot\rVert_V}'$

Comment: Note that the fraction above should be $\frac{ \|\cdot\|_{W'} }{ \|\cdot\|_{V'} } \leq \frac{ D\|\cdot\|_{W} }{ c\|\cdot\|_{V} }$.